# Is it bad practice to keep "this.setState" methods on one line?

Tags: reactjs

I am just curious as to whether it is bad (or better) practice to keep `this.setState` on one line of code, especially if only one state variable is being changed.

```
this.setState({
      fruits: { apples: newApples, bananas: newBananas }
    });
```

vs

```
this.setState({fruits: { apples: newApples, bananas: newBananas }});
```

Comment: According to whom? If you are asking it for your workplace, then check the code guidelines, if you are doing it for an open source project you are participating in, check the code guidelines, if it's for your own project, define your code guidelines

Comment: What about keeping the `fruits` definition on one line? It's all about personal preferences and the guidelines of your team. If the code is equally readable in both formats (which is again subjective), it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

Not, it is not, you or your team defines it.
You can also use a formatter like https://prettier.io/ to do it for you.